# what has replaced the document.domconfig in javascript

Tags: javascript, dom

document.domconfig is obsolete and removed. Any heads up on what it was replaced with? Or how can I get the DOMConfiguration which is also obsolete?

Comment: Can you explain what it was?

Comment: It should return a DOMConfiguration Object which reveals numerous configuration features of the current document. Mostly used with XML documents.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Document/domConfig _"This has never been implemented in Mozilla, and has been removed from the DOM specification."_

Comment: Is it possible to develop this object?

Comment: ¯|_(ツ)_/¯ probably.

Comment: Would be grateful with any head way, thanks

Answer (score 0):

*Based on the `javascript` tag and lack of comments to the contrary, I'm assuming this question is about web browsers.*

`document.domConfig` (and the related interface `DOMConfiguration`) was introduced in [W3C DOM Level 3 Core](https://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-DOM-Level-3-Core-20040407/core.html#DOMConfiguration) in 2004.

The standard was *not* created only with web browsers in mind, as a matter of fact [none of the implementations required to become a W3C Recommendation](https://www.w3.org/2003/10/DOM-Level-3-Core-implementations.html) were part of a web browser.

So when the web browser renaissance began, a version of the DOM spec specifically for web browsers was created, now known as [DOM Living Standard](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/). Since there were no implementations of DOMConfiguration (indicating lack of interest from implementers and presumably web developers, particularly because many of the features are not relevant to the HTML DOM), the feature [was simply pruned from the specification](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=615509).

It was not replaced by anything in particular; there was nothing to replace.

*If you asked "I could do X with domConfig, how do I do it in a web browser" you might get a better answer, but for a generic question about an interface with a dozen rather obscure options I guess this is what the answer should be.*